# Finding a way to upload and install the CAP file to multi- pieces of smart cards

Tags: smartcard, javacard, smartcard-reader, globalplatform

Due to the requirement of our project, I need to upload and install the same CAP file to multiple smart cards simultaneously (at least 12 at once).

Does this need a tool or something else (as I'm not going to spend too much money for this)?

I have tried to google, but found nothing.

Is there any simple method to do this? Or any suggestions?

Comment: @vlp.  Thanks for editing the question for me.

Comment: You are welcome. I think you really should tell some more about the reason why you need this (e.g. to personalize many cards, to do some tests that need a freshly loaded cap...).

Comment: In fact, I am doing card initialization for small quantity card production.

Comment: I have seen this demo vedio -  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHmvrrYG_W8&spfreload=10 -  about card production  from Youtube before.  It may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard and usual procedure to upload and install Javacard Applets (.cap files) is through Global Platform. Almost every javacard compatible card out there is GP-compatible. Make sure that you buy cards that support Javacard! The Global Platform specification is pretty long and complicated. Fortunately there are plenty of tools with varying quality out there that do the job for you.

[Global Platform Pro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro) from Martin Paljak is probably the best freeware tool.

The website is very informative and includes a [list of alternative Global Platform tools](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro#similar-projects)

To install multiple cards at once, you either place card after card and loop your script or you need 12 card readers and run the tool simulaniously. But seriously, I don't see any usecase where this is necessary.
Good luck!

Comment: In this way, I should operate  this one by one. Is there a much better  tool /way for my requirement？

Comment: Well my favorite tool is the JCOP Shell but this one is not freely available. The Global Platform Pro tool is very good and suits all your needs. There is no tool that specializes in installing 12 cards simultaniously

Comment: Hi Paul. Thank you for your answer.  I will have a try.